# Not getting results even with long datetime formats in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to get some data that has datetime set, using the long format(ex: 2019-04-26 18:02:42).

When I use the following query I expected to find the following entry:

```
SELECT ip, cam_id
FROM test_table
WHERE ( date_time >= '2019-04-26 20:00:00' AND date_time <'2019-04-26 20:59:59' );
```

Entry:

```
 id  | ip | cam_id |      date_time
-----+----+--------+---------------------
   1 | 13 |      2 | 2019-04-26 20:46:06
```

However I am not getting any results. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Table schema

```
 Kolon   |       Veri tipi        | S²ralama (collation) | Bo■ (null) olabilir |               Varsay²lan               | Saklama  | Stats hedefi | A²klama
-----------+------------------------+----------------------+---------------------+----------------------------------------+----------+--------------+----------
 id        | integer                |                      | not null            | nextval('test_table_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              |
 ip        | integer                |                      |                     |                                        | plain    |              |
 cam_id    | integer                |                      |                     |                                        | plain    |              |
 date_time | character varying(255) |                      |                     |                                        | extended |              |
¦ndeksler:
    "test_table_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

Comment: What is the data type of `date_time`?  I'm speculating that there is a timezone involved.

Comment: I used https://www.generatedata.com/ to get random dates. I configured "Data Type" as "Date", Examples as "MySQL datetime". I left the format as it is which was "Y-m-d H:i:s" EDIT: also checked on psql and it says "character varying". I am new to SQL so don't know if this was what you meant.

Comment: The date_time column is character varying?  If you are using psql, you can verify this using \d test_table

Comment: You are probably doing lots of wrong, show us schema for that table, if you used generatedata.com generator   created table shema, "MySQL datetime" definitely was varchar(255) not timestamp which you need

Comment: @Jeremy yes it is character varying(255)

Comment: Storing timestamps in a `varchar` column is a **really**, really bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to postgresql, you should start first by reading postgresql manual and examples only. Dont use any kind of third party or unrelated code and sql generators, especialy unrelated to postgresql, those will only confuse you.

Currently, your query is comparing strings not datetime.

if you run this query, it will change date_time columns  character varying(255) type to timestamp one, then your query will run properly:

```
alter table test_table alter column date_time TYPE timestamp without time zone using date_time::timestamp without time zone
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to convert `string` to `datetime` format:

```
CONVERT(datetime, YOUR_COLUMN, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm')
```

Comment: I am pretty new to SQL, where exactly I do this conversion? can I do it in my SELECT statement and simply replace '2019-04-26 20:00:00' with CONVERT(datetime,'2019-04-26 23:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm')?

Comment: @LongBeard_Boldy . . . I don't think this syntax will work on *any* database.  At least, I would be curious what database supports it.